# How to restore the table which accidently deleted in sql using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am doing a project in php Laravel. I am beginner. Accidently I have deleted a table in sql in phpmyadmin.

Now how to recreate that table from php. Not by using sql command.

Comment: Do you have any backups? If not, you need to recreate the table. Otherwise, you can restore it from the backup.

Comment: Restore of the table has two components.
1. schema to be restored.
2. data to be restored.

1.) can be done using migration if you use or any VCS for create script.
2.) if you do your backups regularly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the table without data, I can give you a simple solution for your problem

Usually, when you do the migration, the Laravel will compare the list of files between  `migrations` table and `/database/migrations` folder, if a file exists on the folder and not entered on `migrations` table then it'll execute the file and make the entry.

So, find the migration file name which creates your table on `migrations` table and deletes that row from the database, run the command `php artisan migrate`

this will create the new table

Note: We don't prefer this mostly, but for your problem, it'll be simple

Answer (score 0):

from the command line type `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` however please be advised this will also delete any data in your database.

There is no way to restore the data you have deleted